# Linux: Console apt-get not available?

Tags: linux, apt-get

I need to install Java, Solr, and update Git on this dedicated server.

I have ssh root access and was going to use the `apt-get` method to install what I need. But says this command is not found. Is this not a core Linux thing? I am guess I need to now look into installing this before doing anything else?

I don't have CPanel access.

Comment: No, `apt-get` is not a "core linux" thing. It's one of many possible package managers. If `apt-get` is not installed, you definitely should *not* install it. Use whichever package manager *is* installed. Figure out which distribution of Linux you're working with, and then look up how to correctly install packages on that distribution.

Comment: To expand on meagar's comment: Check /etc/issue.

Comment: @tommyo I checked /etc/. It's yum, guessing this is a CentOS then. This is great to know for the future. Thanks for the help. If you want you can answer the question and I'll mark it.

Comment: Geez, every time I open a question it immediately gets down votes. Thank for the info too @meagar. New to a lot of this stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is solved. I did not know there was a different package manager with CentOS and Ubuntu. I used `yum` and it worked. I will mark this answered once I am able.